# Lazy evaluation of Scala Enumerations?

Tags: scala, object, enumeration

Consider the following code snippet that alphabetizes all digits from 1 to 9:

```
object AlphabetizedDigit extends Enumeration {
    type AlphabetizedDigit = Value
    val one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine = Value
}

println(for(i <- Range(0, AlphabetizedDigit.maxId)) yield (i, AlphabetizedDigit(i)))
```

Because of zero-indexing, the output of `println` will be a bit un-intuitive:

```
jason@debian:~/code/atomicscala$ scala EnumIDRange.scala 
Vector((0,one), (1,two), (2,three), (3,four), (4,five), (5,six), (6,seven), (7,eight), (8,nine))
```

One way to deal with this is to change the definitions of `AlphabetizedDigit`'s members as follows:

```
val one = Value(1)
val two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine = Value
```

and then make sure that `Range` begins from `1` instead of `0`. The output then is the intuitive one:

```
jason@debian:~/code/atomicscala$ scala EnumIDRange.scala 
Vector((1,one), (2,two), (3,three), (4,four), (5,five), (6,six), (7,seven), (8,eight), (9,nine))
```

However, I don't really like the fact that you need to split the declarations in two lines if you just want to switch the starting index of an enumeration. Therefore, I tried the following, which compiles just fine:

```
val one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine = Value(1)
```

But, at runtime, I get an `AssertionError` thrown because of a duplicate ID used. It makes a lot of sense to me that this would not work, but I'm curious about why this error was thrown at runtime instead of compile time.

Comment: Because scala at the moment is not a dependent-typed language and it cant understand that you are feeding same id to different values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the source code for Scala's Enumeration](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L1), you will see the following:

```
/** The cache listing all values of this enumeration. */
@transient private var vset: ValueSet = null
@transient @volatile private var vsetDefined = false
```

and:

```
/** The values of this enumeration as a set.
 */
def values: ValueSet = {
  if (!vsetDefined) {
    vset = (ValueSet.newBuilder ++= vmap.values).result()
    vsetDefined = true
  }
  vset
}
```

So it seems that the set of values is not actually evaluated until required, so the error only shows up at runtime. This does seem like a poor way of implementing `Enumeration`, but I usually prefer working with a sealed trait and case classes and objects, so rarely deal with `Enumeration`s anyway *shrug*.

As for the issue of indexing from `0`, why not add a `zero` entry?

```
val zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine = Value
```

You could still count from 1 if you want:

```
scala> println(for(i <- Range(1, AlphabetizedDigit.maxId)) yield (i, AlphabetizedDigit(i)))
Vector((1,one), (2,two), (3,three), (4,four), (5,five), (6,six), (7,seven), (8,eight), (9,nine))
```

or just count from 0 and get all ten digits:

```
println(for(i <- Range(0, AlphabetizedDigit.maxId)) yield (i, AlphabetizedDigit(i)))
Vector((0,zero), (1,one), (2,two), (3,three), (4,four), (5,five), (6,six), (7,seven), (8,eight), (9,nine))
```

Comment: Thanks, there did seem to exist some kind of laziness in the evaluation of the `Enumeration`'s values, and the if condition that initializes `vset` does exactly that. As for your question on proper indexing of `AlphabetizedDigit`'s members, I completely agree with the obvious solution of putting a `zero` member: this was a more simplified example of a larger code that I was fiddling with.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the second constructor of Enumeration, for example:

```
object AlphabetizedDigit extends Enumeration(1) {
    type AlphabetizedDigit = Value
    val one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine = Value
}
```

form doc: `new Enumeration(initial: Int)`.

Comment: Ah, this solves the motivating problem in a much more elegant way and is something I really should've found myself through the docs. In the process, however, I learnt something about how `Enumeration`'s work, so that's also good. Thanks.